# How to export a range of rows in MS SQL?

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I am wondering how I can export a range of rows from a table in MS SQL. Lets say I have 1,000,000 rows in a table but I need the rows 900,000 - 1,000,000 exported into a text file. Is that possible and how can it be done?

Comment: You can use SSIS to export these rows to a text or CSV file. The SQL language itself doesn't have that feature. One note though is that SQL tables don't have a concept of "order". You need to define what orders these rows are sorted by.

Comment: Adhoc: You can do something like `select * from table where id between 900000 and 1000000 order by id` in Management Studio, and run it.  Then right click the results and save as CSV.  To automate it, go the SSIS route as mentioned.